# How to have unique URLs for a single dynamic page?

Tags: url, iis, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I think my question may be worded incorrectly but heres what I want to do (for SEO purposes).

I have a page that gives a logo and description of a brand e.g. Volvo. I want to use this same page as a template for all manufacturers but just change a few words around to customize it for each manufacturer accordingly. So in the URL I pass it a variable of the manufacturer e.g. "www.example.com/cars.cfm?manufacturer=BMW" and it will show a page that gives information about BMW.

The problem is that for each manufacturer the information is still showing up as the same page "cars.cfm" in the address bar but really I want it to go to a URL like "www.example.com/manufacturers/volvo.cfm" so it appears as a unique page just for that brand. But at the same time I don't want to have to create a seperate CFM (or php/asp) page for each manufacturer.

Is there a clever way to do this at all? I imagine its something to do with URL rewriting but not sure. I am using IIS 7.5.

---

Creating numerous sub-folders for different car manufacturers is going to be very tedious. My site would also include other types of manufacturers for different products not just cars. I guess URL rewriting would be best but my idea was to have a different 'page' for each manufacturer so the SEO would be improved.

Basically....

```
www.example.com/manufacturers/audi.cfm 
www.example.com/manufacturers/bmw.cfm 
www.example.com/manufactueres/volkswagen.cfm
```

But really I want the data on each of those pages to come from a database which contains unique data for each manufacturer such the logo image and history description.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
http://www.fivestarautocentre.co.uk <-- go to bottom of that page and you can see links to various manufacturers
```

Comment: What you're trying to do can be accomplished by URL Routing. With a route like `www.example.com/manufacturers/{id}`, the request www.example.com/manufacturers/BMW will route to the whatever handles the request for www.example.com/manufacturers with a request parameter `id=BMW`

Comment: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite is the re-write filter for IIS which everyone seems to use. That'll let you do what you want, with the possible downside that you're then bound to a particular web server. Look at the Tuckey re-write filter for a platform-independent solution if that matters to you

Comment: This URL rewrite is also widely used, and based on Apache's mod_rewrite: http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

Comment: Tuckey rewriting occurs on the servlet side (i.e. Jrun/Tomcat) - if a web server is involved there's no reason to wait to do the URL rewriting, so either use IIS's built-in functionality or the Helicon plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what everyone else said, start by creating your `www.example.com/cars.cfm?manufacturer=BMW` page and get that working.

Assuming you're on IIS you would then create a `web.config` file (if it isn't already there) in your root folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Cars-Rewrite">
                <match url="manufacturer/(\w+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/cars.cfm?manufacturer={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
```

My regex could be off, but maybe someone else could chime in with the correct regex.

Comment: Needs to be at least `(\w+)` - otherwise it'll only match a single char. Beyond that it depends what manufacturer might contain - could also use `([^/?#]+)` to catch any non-slash character.

Comment: I want the search engine crawler to think it has gone to a unique content static page rather than the same page but with different content dynamically added. Do you think URL rewriting is the way to do it?

Comment: URL rewriting gives tidier URLs, which benefits humans (which is who your site is for). Don't worry too much about crawlers.

Comment: A key thing to make a dynamic page act more static is to use appropriate caching - including sending `Last-Modified` headers then checking incoming requests for `If-Modified-Since` headers and (when appropriate) responding with `304 Not Modified` instead of doing the processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly handle this with URL rewriting as others have suggested but I think I would take a different approach.  Particularly for SEO purposes.  The best solution for SEO will be an actual URL for each brand.  With that in mind create your site accordingly.  Don't use a generic www.example.com/cars.cfm page, use www.example.com/bmw, www.example.com/volvo, etc.  You can still have a ColdFusion page under each of those folders that does nothing more than include your generic ColdFusion template from another location (or call a cfc).  Since each folder will have it's own unique stub file you can pass the appropriate vehicle manufacturer when the generic ColdFusion template is called.  For example, under the www.example.com/bmw page:

```
<cfset manufacturer = "bmw" />
<cfinclude template="/mytemplates/genericpage.cfm" />
```

Then your genericpage.cfm uses the assigned variable to display the appropriate text and graphics.  You could even get around having to set a particular variable under each folder by parsing the URL and grabbing the manufacturer from it when the template is included and executed.  I believe the `cgi.script_name` variable will contain the path needed to do this.

Comment: This is clever.  Could he just process that with those lines in index.cfm using the same URL structure?

Comment: @KRC not sure what you mean by 'same URL structure'.  What I am suggesting is that he create an actual folder for each vehicle manufacturer.  The generic page that gets included in each of those can be located elsewhere and referenced via a ColdFusion mapping or some such.

Comment: Creating actual folders is not a particularly scalable solution. It's far simpler to just do URL rewriting.

Comment: @PeterBoughton If you are comfortable with URL rewriting it is simpler.  Plus we are talking about vehicle manufacturers that do not change very often.  I am just offering another alternative.

Comment: URL rewriting _is_ simpler. (Not knowing how to do something doesn't change its complexity!)

Comment: Even if the scope were limited to car manufacturers (it isn't), creating over 125 folders each with a single file is not a good way to approach this problem.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I'm afraid I disagree with your comment that 'Not knowing how to do something doesn't change its complexity!'  Technically speaking the complexity doesn't change but the perception, ability and knowledge of each individual person will make something more complicated for them.  Building a website is not complicated for me but if I ask my dad to do it, it will be complicated for him.

Comment: Regardless of our differing point of views on the complexity, I actually do agree with you that using URL rewriting would work for this.  I stated so at the beginning of my answer.  I just thought I would offer an alternative approach for the OP if he/she has no knowledge of URL rewriting.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm talking about complexity, not difficulty. It's relevant here because a complex system is slower than a simple system. Url rewriting will not just work, it will work faster, more efficiently, with less maintainance, etc. **Even if the OP needs to learn it, URL rewriting is the better option here.**

Comment: In general, folders are for grouping different files - if you have a situation where you've got multiple folders with individual (and almost identical) files, you need to think "what am I doing here", because there's very likely a better approach.

Comment: @Miguel I was aware that's what you were suggesting, and I agree with Peter; my comment was having those values passed directly to index.cfm; basically making the manufacturer an event handler value.  It's simpler and cleaner to use a URL rewrite.